# Bootstrap 4 losing content with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js

Well basically my problem is that when I'm scrolling down when using the fullPage.js, I loose the content of my 'Section0, I don't know if it is the lack of sleep but I can't find the problem, I'm linking the codepen so you can try it live, thanks in advance!

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section fp-auto-height" id="section0">
    <!-- Fin del menú de navegación -->
      <div class="banner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="intro">
          <h1 class="jumbotitle">BRAND LOGO</h1>    
          <p class="jumboparr">¡Some text for information!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section1">
   <div class="slide sd1" id="slide1">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <p class="sdp1">More info bla bla blaa </p>
         <p class="sdp1">The same info different color</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide sd2" id="slide2">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <p class="sdp2">¡Moooore infoooo lorem impsum! </p>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/grbstudios-the-styleful/pen/XBWmKZ)

Comment: You are not lossing anything. You only have 2 sections. Your problem is the 1st section is huge. So you won't be able to see it all unless you use something like the fullpage.js option `scrollOverflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `.banner {height:800px;}`. If you change it, for example, in `height:100vh` you can see your content.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjdPpz

```css
.navbar{
  background: black !important;
}
#header, #footer {
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:9;
}
#header {
  top:0px;
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/009/439/993/large/brody-bellon-background-space-sm.jpg?1519023411") !important;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  color: white !important;
}
.nav-link {
  color: white !important; 
}
.nl1:hover {
  color: #9933ff !important;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive !important;
}
.nl2:hover {
  color: #ffcc00 !important;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive !important;
}

.sd1 {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}
.sd2 {
  background-color: #9933ff;
}
.sdp1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.sdp2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.jumbotitle {
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.jumboparr {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme|Fjalla+One|Francois+One|Oswald|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Scroll Plugin de fullpage.js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.1/fullpage.css">
    <!-- This following line is only necessary in the case of using the option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.1/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.1/fullpage.js"></script>

    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>

  <body>

   <div id="header">
    <!-- Menú de navegación -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND TEST</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link nl2" href="home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link nl1" href="#">Galeria</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link nl2" href="#">Noticias</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link nl1" href="#">Equipo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link nl2" href="#">Contacto</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section fp-auto-height" id="section0">
      <!-- Fin del menú de navegación -->
   <div class="banner">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="intro">
         <h1 class="jumbotitle">BRAND LOGO</h1> 
       <p class="jumboparr">¡Some text for information!</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide sd1" id="slide1">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <p class="sdp1">More info bla bla blaa </p>
       <p class="sdp1">The same info different color</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide sd2" id="slide2">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <p class="sdp2">¡Moooore infoooo lorem impsum! </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
      anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage'],
      sectionsColor: ['#ffcc00', '#9933ff'],
      fixedElements: '#header'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, but can you explain why it did? (also, I added a margin-top to the text elements because they where too much on the top) Ty!

Comment: Sure! If you put a banner height 800px, sometimes it is heighter than window height so your content is hidden at the top (use Firefox or Chrome DevTools to understand this bug). With 100vh you're sure it's as height as your browser window (i.e. .section div) and you can see your content. So you have put some padding to add some space on the top. Correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should need to remove "fp-auto-height" class from section0.